# Magento minimum qty allowed for particular product

Tags: magento-1.9

How to set up the minimum qty for particular product ?
[image]

Comment: You want it for all products or particular product?

Answer (score 1):

You can set this for particular product.
Click `Inventory` tab in left menu/tab, while adding/editing products. In right side you can see `Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart`. Here you can set minimum Qty. But yu will have to uncheck `Use Config Settings` checkbox for this option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I want to show the notification if the customer select below minimum qty.Eg: i gave minimum qty 5.If the customer selects 3.In view page i want to display notification message.

Answer (score 1):

- Login to admin panel and go to **`Catalog -> Manage Products`**.
- Click on any product to edit or click on **`Add Product`** button.
- Click on **`Inventory`** tab.
- Uncheck **`Use Config Settings`** check box for **`Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart`** field and put appropriate value for the field.
- Click on **`Save`** button.

That's all. Please check screenshot for reference.

[image: Edit Product]

Comment: How to display an error message supposed customer choose to add beyond the qty in a cart.

Comment: If backorder is not enabled, Magento will automatically show an error message if the customer tries to add more than allowed quantity.

Comment: Backorder disable. Screen Shot -> https://snag.gy/7ghlAv.jpg, still the error message not shown in the frontend.

Comment: May i know what i need to do next?

Answer (score 0):

You can add minimum allow quantity for all product from admin

```
Admin >> System >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Inventory >> Product Stock Options >> Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart >> Minimum Qty.
```

Or for particular product

```
Admin >> Catalog >> Product >> Open product which you want to add >> Inventory >> Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have  set the qty.But i didn't get notification for qty i have to set 5 only. i have  selected 2 in my qty box. after adding to cart its showing 5 qty its fine.But i should get the notification like u must select qty 5 only like that

Comment: Hi Suresh, I have a product with qty is 5, supposed if a customer adds 10 quantity in cart how can I display the message like you are selected exceeded amount of quantity.